# Ruby Sinatra/Postgres - can't connect to heroku database with PG.connect?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku, sinatra

I am trying to get a site set up on Heroku using Sinatra and PostgreSQL. It worked locally (connecting to local database), but after pushing it to Heroku and changing my `PG.connect` to reflect that, I get an **Internal Server Error** the moment a page tries to access the database.

```
require 'uri'
require 'pg'

uri = URI.parse(ENV['DATABASE_URL'])

def db(uri)
  begin
    connection = PG.connect(uri.hostname, uri.port, nil, nil, uri.path[1..-1], uri.user, uri.password)
    yield(connection)
  ensure
    connection.close
  end
end
```

I am pretty sure these are parsing correctly, because `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` displays the full `postgres://user:password@host:port/database` information that I'm expecting, and if I do the same in IRB uri.hostname, ui.port, etc all return what's expected .

This is my first time trying to get a site working on Heroku, so I am not even sure how to troubleshoot this. (And I googled for about all of yesterday.)

Results for `heroku pg`:

```
=== DATABASE_URL
Plan:        Hobby-dev
Status:      Available
Connections: 0/20
PG Version:  9.4.2
Created:     2015-05-30 19:24 UTC
Data Size:   17.7 MB
Tables:      5
Rows:        9320/10000 (In compliance, close to row limit)
Fork/Follow: Unsupported
Rollback:    Unsupported
```

And all the tables show up when when I do `heroku pg:psql <database>` from the cli.

Some answers I've seen said to add `database.yml` to my root app directory, so:

```
production:
  adapter: 'postgresql'
  database: '<database>'
  host: ENV['DATABASE_URL']
  username: '<username>'
```

There's probably something simple I'm missing, but I haven't seen a complete guide for Sinatra/PSQL on Heroku - nothing that goes specifically into setting up and connecting to your database. (Everything seems Rails-related.)

Comment: What do your logs say?

Comment: Not sure why I didn't get email alerts for replies... Logs just say "No method 'close' for nil class", so `PG.connect` is not finding the database and returning nil instead

Comment: Shouldn’t `PG.connect` raise an error if it can’t connect?

Comment: I thought so.. Testing it locally, if I supply a nonexistent database, it kicks up a `PG::ConnectionBad` error. If I supply zero parameters or `nil`, it returns a `PG::Connection` object which can be `.close`d. So I'm really not sure how it's getting to `close` at all without either giving an error beforehand or returning a connection object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `database.yml` file you need to specify the correct host for the `host` entry. You are passing what is stored in `DATABASE_URL` (something like `postgres://user:password@host:port/database`) but it should just be the host.

You will also need to specify a port if it isn't the default for PostgreSQL.

Edit: should also point out if you plan to store the host (or anything else - you definitely should for username and password) in an environment variable you'll need to wrap it, e.g. `<%= ENV['HOST'] %>`, not just `ENV['HOST']` (i.e. how you have in the database.yml excerpt above)

Comment: Hmm okay, that first part makes sense - I overlooked that I was passing the full URL instead of just the host portion.

If I'm populating the database.yml with <%= ENV['HOST'] %>, what would the others be? 'PORT', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD', etc?

I'm also just really confused about database.yml in general - I thought the `PG.connect` in my `db` would be the only thing responsible for connecting to the database. I've seen so many different tutorials and posts, some just use PG gem, some use database.yml, some are passing stuff in through a config.ru...

Comment: There is no environment variable for `HOST` - you would need to set it (you don't even need to call it `HOST`, you can call it `ZOMBIES` if you want) as well as any others you don't want to hardcode into the file. If you're unfamiliar with environment variables in general or with use on Heroku I'd suggest reading their [guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) - but basically you'll do something like `heroku config:set HOST=myhost.com` and then use `<%= ENV['HOST'] %>` in your database.yml file.

Comment: Somehow nothing I read mentioned setting up those environment variables, thanks.. I've set those up, and I know that my app can access them (I had them render on the root view briefly), and I fixed my database.yml and `PG.connect` calls to use those instead of parsing them from the URI... Still the same result - call to `.connect` returns `nil`

Comment: You might find this [tutorial](https://samuelstern.wordpress.com/2012/11/28/making-a-simple-database-driven-website-with-sinatra-and-heroku/) useful. Also, if you haven't gotten too far with your current project and aren't terribly beholden to Sinatra you may want to consider using [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) instead, which comes with an ORM (ActiveRecord) out of the box which will greatly simplify accessing the database (i.e. you won't need to manage connections).

Comment: Nice link, thanks! Sinatra's been incredibly useful to learn a lot of the basics that Rails keeps 'hidden' (to us newbies), but.. No, I'm not terribly beholden to it - I had really just been hoping to get a demo app online, but I think I'll wait until we've gotten into ActiveRecord for Sinatra and Rails. I appreciate the help!